# Extracting specific data from EnableOutput in OR-Tools every 10 seconds

Tags: python, solver, or-tools

I've been using OR-Tools with the SCIP solver, specifically using the following setup:

```py
self.solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver('SCIP')
self.solver.EnableOutput()
status = self.solver.Solve()
```

While the solver is running, the `EnableOutput` method provides a detailed console output with a lot of useful information, like this:

```
time | node  | left  |LP iter|LP it/n|mem/heur|mdpt |vars |cons |rows |cuts |sepa|confs|strbr|  dualbound   | primalbound  |  gap   | compl. 
111s|  8200 |   131 |980573 |  83.9 |    63M |  69 | 693 |1489 |1195 |6281 |  0 |  13k|5395 | 1.302965e+04 | 1.401400e+04 |   7.55%|  77.77%
112s|  8300 |    60 |992733 |  84.2 |    63M |  69 | 693 |1498 | 801 |6443 |  1 |  13k|5446 | 1.317840e+04 | 1.401400e+04 |   6.34%|  91.13%
```

For my specific use-case, I'd like to capture specific data points from this output, say, the gap, every 10 seconds while the solver is running. Is there a built-in way within OR-Tools to extract this data? I suspect that OR-Tools might not be printing through the standard Python output and error channels, which makes capturing the output a challenge. Alternatively, I'm open to monitoring and parsing the console output using external tools or methods if that's a recommended approach. I'd like to note that I've tried using the `sys` module, but it hasn't worked for my needs.

Any guidance, recommendations, or workarounds would be much appreciated.

Comment: Nothing in OR-Tools. It is not OR-Tools but SCIP that prints out to stderr.

Comment: @LaurentPerron Thank you for your response. Is there a way to change the configuration of SCIP (in Google OR-Tools) so that the output is written to a log file? Or are there other ways to capture the output? Thank you.

Comment: No. If your problem does not have continuous variables, you should the 'sat' backend (CP-SAT-LP0). It is a better solver than SCIP. And you can redirect the log (see https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/1d696f9108a0ebfd99feb73b9211e2f5a6b0812b/ortools/sat/python/cp_model_test.py#L1386)

Comment: @LaurentPerron Thank you for your response. My program is an algorithm for automated staff scheduling. So far, I've incorporated about 15 constraints, and the code is quite advanced. The issue is that the solution time sometimes takes several hours. No continuous variables are used. Would the CpSolver be a better and faster alternative? Does it make sense to restructure my code? Up until now, I've been using the SCIP Solver through Google OR-Tools. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Cp-sat with at least 8 cores is much faster than scip, and does not need the continuous variable trick.

Comment: @LaurentPerron Thank you for the quick response. I have rewritten a large portion of the code in CP-SAT. The solver is significantly faster now. I have a question regarding the solving process. The solver quickly finds a very good solution, but then remains stuck at the same point for minutes. Is this normal, and is it possible to print the current progress of the solver every 5 seconds? Thank you very much. (for example:)                                                                               
#13     10.64s best:12400 next:[11900,12375] graph_var_lns(d=0.49 s=98 t=0.10 p=0.50 stall=3)

Comment: can you send me the model: model.ExportToFile('slow_model.pb.txt'), compress the file? Are you using 9.7 ?

Comment: @LaurentPerron Of course, I will merge my code this weekend and send you the model afterwards. How can I send it to you? Via email? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes email. It is easy to find at Google.

Comment: @LaurentPerron I have now sent my program to two emails I found associated with you. I hope one of the emails is correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solving with CP-SAT on my laptop with 10 workers:

```
Starting search at 0.43s with 10 workers.
8 full problem subsolvers: [core, default_lp, max_lp, no_lp, pseudo_costs, quick_restart, quick_restart_no_lp, reduced_costs]
8 incomplete subsolvers: [feasibility_pump, graph_arc_lns, graph_cst_lns, graph_dec_lns, graph_var_lns, rins/rens, rnd_cst_lns, rnd_var_lns]
3 helper subsolvers: [neighborhood_helper, synchronization_agent, update_gap_integral]
#Bound   0.50s best:inf   next:[23500,53657720] default_lp initial_propagation
#Bound   1.71s best:inf   next:[23909,53657720] max_lp
#1       8.33s best:713602 next:[23909,713601] pseudo_costs fixed_bools:0/9208
#2       8.43s best:713306 next:[23909,713305] quick_restart_no_lp fixed_bools:0/8813
#3       8.49s best:712603 next:[23909,712602] rnd_var_lns(d=0.50 s=662 t=0.10 p=0.00 stall=0) [hint]
#4       8.71s best:712307 next:[23909,712306] quick_restart_no_lp fixed_bools:0/8816
#5       8.71s best:585314 next:[23909,585313] rens_lp_lns(d=0.68 s=661 t=0.10 p=0.45 stall=0)
#6       8.83s best:560203 next:[23909,560202] quick_restart_no_lp fixed_bools:0/10569
#7       8.89s best:559907 next:[23909,559906] quick_restart_no_lp fixed_bools:0/10569
#8       8.90s best:559870 next:[23909,559869] quick_restart_no_lp fixed_bools:0/10569
#9       9.20s best:534845 next:[23909,534844] quick_restart_no_lp fixed_bools:0/10591
#10      9.26s best:534808 next:[23909,534807] graph_dec_lns(d=0.50 s=667 t=0.10 p=0.00 stall=0) [hint]
#11      9.28s best:534549 next:[23909,534548] quick_restart_no_lp fixed_bools:0/10624
#Bound   9.43s best:534549 next:[25971,534548] max_lp
#12      9.44s best:534512 next:[25971,534511] quick_restart_no_lp fixed_bools:0/11988
#13      9.48s best:509785 next:[25971,509784] quick_restart_no_lp fixed_bools:0/14778
#14      9.52s best:509760 next:[25971,509759] rnd_cst_lns(d=0.29 s=669 t=0.10 p=0.00 stall=0)
#15      9.67s best:484760 next:[25971,484759] quick_restart_no_lp fixed_bools:0/14790
#16      9.67s best:484649 next:[25971,484648] quick_restart_no_lp fixed_bools:0/14790
#17      9.68s best:484499 next:[25971,484498] quick_restart_no_lp fixed_bools:0/14790
#18      9.70s best:484425 next:[25971,484424] quick_restart_no_lp fixed_bools:0/14791
#19      9.74s best:389511 next:[25971,389510] rnd_var_lns(d=0.71 s=668 t=0.10 p=1.00 stall=0)
#20      9.88s best:389361 next:[25971,389360] quick_restart_no_lp fixed_bools:0/14808
#21     10.06s best:364361 next:[25971,364360] quick_restart_no_lp fixed_bools:0/14810
#22     10.10s best:364215 next:[25971,364214] rnd_var_lns(d=0.54 s=674 t=0.10 p=0.50 stall=0)
#23     10.14s best:339215 next:[25971,339214] quick_restart_no_lp fixed_bools:0/14865
#24     10.26s best:339178 next:[25971,339177] quick_restart_no_lp fixed_bools:0/14913
#25     10.29s best:289311 next:[25971,289310] graph_dec_lns(d=0.71 s=673 t=0.10 p=1.00 stall=0)
#26     10.45s best:289198 next:[25971,289197] quick_restart_no_lp fixed_bools:0/15076

...

#166    95.55s best:34389 next:[27962,34388] quick_restart_no_lp fixed_bools:1109/23063
#167    95.89s best:34239 next:[27962,34238] quick_restart_no_lp fixed_bools:1109/23065
#168    95.99s best:34202 next:[27962,34201] quick_restart_no_lp fixed_bools:1109/23068
#169    97.47s best:34165 next:[27962,34164] quick_restart_no_lp fixed_bools:1109/23163
#170    97.52s best:34128 next:[27962,34127] quick_restart_no_lp fixed_bools:1109/23170
#Bound  98.71s best:34128 next:[27982,34127] max_lp
#171   102.18s best:33980 next:[27982,33979] graph_cst_lns(d=0.47 s=1530 t=0.10 p=0.51 stall=5)
#172   102.34s best:33832 next:[27982,33831] quick_restart_no_lp fixed_bools:1109/23338
#173   123.31s best:33715 next:[27982,33714] rnd_var_lns(d=0.81 s=1724 t=0.10 p=0.51 stall=4)
#174   123.43s best:33567 next:[27982,33566] graph_arc_lns(d=0.19 s=1727 t=0.10 p=0.49 stall=64)
#175   123.85s best:33530 next:[27982,33529] rnd_var_lns(d=0.83 s=1730 t=0.10 p=0.51 stall=0)
#176   125.95s best:33306 next:[27982,33305] graph_dec_lns(d=0.82 s=1747 t=0.10 p=0.51 stall=3)
#177   126.20s best:33232 next:[27982,33231] quick_restart_no_lp fixed_bools:1109/23889
#178   178.46s best:33076 next:[27982,33075] graph_dec_lns(d=0.81 s=2209 t=0.10 p=0.51 stall=10)
#179   179.19s best:33002 next:[27982,33001] graph_dec_lns(d=0.79 s=2215 t=0.10 p=0.50 stall=0)
#180   179.24s best:32632 next:[27982,32631] rnd_var_lns(d=0.84 s=2216 t=0.10 p=0.51 stall=0)
#181   188.15s best:32032 next:[27982,32031] graph_var_lns(d=0.36 s=2290 t=0.10 p=0.51 stall=17)
#182   192.88s best:31882 next:[27982,31881] graph_dec_lns(d=0.81 s=2329 t=0.10 p=0.51 stall=2)
```

Comment: Thank you for running the program. It seems that your laptop calculates significantly faster or I might have set something wrong in my solver... I posted the entire answer further down below.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for running the program. It seems that your laptop calculates significantly faster or I might have set something wrong in my solver. (My processor: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz 2.80 GHz). Below, you can see the outputs I receive with my computer. Are there any other settings in the solver that I can adjust? Many thanks.

**Default settings:**

```
self.model = cp_model.CpModel()
self.solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
...
```

**Objective function:**

```
...
total_cost = sum(cost_expressions)
self.model.Minimize(total_cost)
...
self.solver.parameters.log_search_progress = True
self.status = self.solver.Solve(self.model)
```

**Output:**

```
Starting search at 1.20s with 8 workers.
6 full problem subsolvers: [core, default_lp, max_lp, no_lp, pseudo_costs, reduced_costs]
1 first solution subsolver: [jump]
8 incomplete subsolvers: [feasibility_pump, graph_arc_lns, graph_cst_lns, graph_dec_lns, graph_var_lns, rins/rens, rnd_cst_lns, rnd_var_lns]
3 helper subsolvers: [neighborhood_helper, synchronization_agent, update_gap_integral]
#Bound   1.45s best:inf   next:[23500,53657720] default_lp initial_propagation
#1       1.95s best:9805718 next:[23500,9805717] jump(batch:1 #lin_moves:3'142/2'797'941 #weight_updates:263)
#2       2.12s best:6373307 next:[23500,6373306] rnd_var_lns(d=0.50 s=10 t=0.10 p=0.00 stall=0)
#Bound   3.59s best:6373307 next:[24425,6373306] pseudo_costs
#3       3.61s best:6220660 next:[24425,6220659] rnd_cst_lns(d=0.50 s=11 t=0.10 p=0.00 stall=0) [hint]
#Bound   4.22s best:6220660 next:[24550,6220659] pseudo_costs
#4       5.10s best:5994262 next:[24550,5994261] graph_cst_lns(d=0.50 s=14 t=0.10 p=0.00 stall=0) [hint]
#5       5.25s best:4932281 next:[24550,4932280] graph_dec_lns(d=0.50 s=15 t=0.10 p=0.00 stall=0) [hint]
#6       5.67s best:1197223 next:[24550,1197222] rins_pump_lns(d=0.50 s=16 t=0.10 p=0.00 stall=0)
#Bound   5.75s best:1197223 next:[25300,1197222] pseudo_costs
#7       6.57s best:864984 next:[25300,864983] graph_var_lns(d=0.29 s=19 t=0.10 p=0.00 stall=0)
#8       7.65s best:838036 next:[25300,838035] graph_arc_lns(d=0.29 s=20 t=0.10 p=0.00 stall=0)
#Bound   9.36s best:838036 next:[25385,838035] pseudo_costs
#9       9.57s best:834945 next:[25385,834944] graph_dec_lns(d=0.71 s=22 t=0.10 p=1.00 stall=0)
#10      9.90s best:809234 next:[25385,809233] rnd_var_lns(d=0.54 s=25 t=0.10 p=0.50 stall=0)
#11     10.96s best:784234 next:[25385,784233] rnd_cst_lns(d=0.46 s=26 t=0.10 p=0.50 stall=1) [hint]
#12     11.70s best:783634 next:[25385,783633] graph_arc_lns(d=0.19 s=28 t=0.10 p=0.00 stall=0)
#13     13.24s best:733750 next:[25385,733749] graph_dec_lns(d=0.54 s=30 t=0.10 p=0.50 stall=0)
#Bound  14.99s best:733750 next:[25390,733749] pseudo_costs
#14     17.95s best:683281 next:[25390,683280] rnd_var_lns(d=0.69 s=33 t=0.10 p=0.67 stall=0)
#Bound  18.70s best:683281 next:[25492,683280] pseudo_costs
#15     19.80s best:658406 next:[25492,658405] graph_arc_lns(d=0.28 s=36 t=0.10 p=0.33 stall=0)
#16     20.60s best:583800 next:[25492,583799] rnd_var_lns(d=0.55 s=41 t=0.10 p=0.50 stall=0)
#17     21.45s best:508969 next:[25492,508968] graph_dec_lns(d=0.69 s=38 t=0.10 p=0.67 stall=0)
#18     21.78s best:459256 next:[25492,459255] graph_var_lns(d=0.21 s=43 t=0.10 p=0.25 stall=0)
#Bound  22.51s best:459256 next:[25529,459255] pseudo_costs
#19     26.50s best:384331 next:[25529,384330] rnd_var_lns(d=0.68 s=49 t=0.10 p=0.60 stall=0)
#Bound  27.32s best:384331 next:[25599,384330] pseudo_costs
#20     28.42s best:294615 next:[25599,294614] max_lp fixed_bools:0/9216
...
#62    171.79s best:35328 next:[29332,35327] graph_dec_lns(d=0.81 s=358 t=0.10 p=0.53 stall=2)
#63    191.19s best:35178 next:[29332,35177] rnd_var_lns(d=0.75 s=401 t=0.10 p=0.51 stall=1)
#64    194.26s best:35102 next:[29332,35101] rnd_var_lns(d=0.78 s=409 t=0.10 p=0.52 stall=0)
#65    196.72s best:35065 next:[29332,35064] rins_pump_lns(d=0.35 s=416 t=0.10 p=0.47 stall=0) [presolve]
#66    203.45s best:34952 next:[29332,34951] rnd_var_lns(d=0.80 s=433 t=0.10 p=0.53 stall=2)
#Model 205.20s var:8249/9290 constraints:6052/6778 compo:8234,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,...
#67    224.74s best:34802 next:[29332,34801] graph_dec_lns(d=0.78 s=478 t=0.10 p=0.52 stall=1)
#68    269.79s best:34765 next:[29332,34764] rnd_var_lns(d=0.81 s=577 t=0.10 p=0.52 stall=5)
#69    273.24s best:34728 next:[29332,34727] graph_dec_lns(d=0.81 s=582 t=0.10 p=0.52 stall=12)
#Model 376.63s var:8248/9290 constraints:6050/6778 compo:8232,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,...
#70    467.85s best:34128 next:[29332,34127] graph_var_lns(d=0.28 s=979 t=0.10 p=0.50 stall=10)
#71    497.88s best:34050 next:[29332,34049] graph_dec_lns(d=0.81 s=1046 t=0.10 p=0.51 stall=2)
#72    511.65s best:33974 next:[29332,33973] graph_dec_lns(d=0.82 s=1070 t=0.10 p=0.52 stall=2)
#73    515.56s best:33676 next:[29332,33675] graph_dec_lns(d=0.81 s=1078 t=0.10 p=0.51 stall=0)
#74    843.56s best:33528 next:[29332,33527] graph_arc_lns(d=0.29 s=1708 t=0.10 p=0.50 stall=5)
#Model 858.46s var:8247/9290 constraints:6048/6778 compo:8230,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,...
#Model 1864.82s var:8246/9290 constraints:6046/6778 compo:8228,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,...
#Model 1911.04s var:8245/9290 constraints:6044/6778 compo:8226,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,...
#Model 2228.47s var:8244/9290 constraints:6042/6778 compo:8224,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,...
```

I waited another 3000s, but after "#Model 2228.47s var:8244/9290 constraints:6042/6778 compo:8224,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,..." nothing else happened and I terminated it."